# getting the total of a nested object property

Tags: javascript

I have a an object as shown below, how can i get the total value of ca from each properties

```
var temp1 = {test1: {ca:1, ba:2, da: 3}, test2: {ca:1, ba:2, da: 3}, test3: { ba:2, da: 3}}
```

sometimes the temp1 can consist of only one property as test1, so inorder to satisfy that case i thoguht of finding the first property of object. But when test2 test3 comes i can't use of 0. Also the property ca can exist or not.

```
temp1[Object.keys(temp1)[0]]
```

i have tried and i am getting the output , but can we improve this one

```
 var arr = []
Object.keys(temp1).forEach(o => {
   Object.keys(temp1[o]).forEach(so => {
     if(so === "ca"){
       arr.push(temp1[o][so])
     }
  })
})

arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b)
```

expected output is

```
 var total = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over the `Object.values()`, you can catch the undefined `ca` with a short circuit like `ca || 0` -- it will use `ca` if it's defined otherwise 0:

```js
var temp1 = {test1: {ca:1, ba:2, da: 3}, test2: {ca:1, ba:2, da: 3}, test3: { ba:2, da: 3}} 

let sum = Object.values(temp1).reduce((sum,{ca}) => sum + (ca || 0), 0)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: @quirimmo, not this just iterates over the values of the object. To go arbitrarily deeper would probably need to do some recursion.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks for the single line code and for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the object and check if the key is present. If it is so then add the value to a variable

```js
var temp1 = {
  test1: {
    ca: 1,
    ba: 2,
    da: 3
  },
  test2: {
    ca: 1,
    ba: 2,
    da: 3
  },
  test3: {
    ba: 2,
    da: 3
  }
}

function valueOfKeyToGet(key) {
  let val = 0;
  for (let keys in temp1) {
    if (temp1[keys][key] !== undefined) {
      val += temp1[keys][key];
    }
  }
  console.log(val)
}
valueOfKeyToGet('ca')
```